# email working on local server but not working on live server AWS using zf3

Tags: zend-framework3

Description:   sending mail from localhost mail working but sending from AWS server mail not working giving error below as i mentioned.

Code:

```
$options = new SmtpOptions();
                $options->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')                                             
                ->setName('smtp.gmail.com')
                ->setPort(587)
                ->setConnectionClass('login')
                ->setConnectionConfig(array(
                                   'username' => 'user@domain.com',
                                   'password' => '123456789',
                                   'ssl' => 'tls',
                                   'host'=>'333.333.333.333', 
                                   'use_complete_quit'   => false,                                                                
                                 )
                      );

                $transport->setOptions($options);                   

                $res = $transport->send($message);
```

Error:
    An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException

File:

```
/var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php:348
```

Message:

```
5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuo
 5.7.14 Px2wvtfOrS5wFFQmXT6hEwb6_1qcc1hT6WbEWXyUx_ySCaHzuDAWuVXje2HQlktgHPhwIi
 5.7.14 8qrKNzgRYBckbmSR5J6_w5JDU5MJHcE-dHh718s0BTmxnsRPpHm970TwgImXzT> Please
 5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.
 5.7.14  Learn more at
 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a9sm10567779iod.76 - gsmtp
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Protocol/Smtp/Auth/Login.php(78): Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol->_expect(Array)
#1 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Protocol/Smtp.php(222): Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp\Auth\Login->auth()
#2 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Smtp.php(401): Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp->helo('smtp.gmail.com')
#3 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Smtp.php(383): Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->connect()
#4 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Smtp.php(394): Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->lazyLoadConnection()
#5 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Smtp.php(251): Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->connect()
#6 /var/www/module/Application/src/Controller/PurchaseController.php(785): Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->send(Object(Zend\Mail\Message))
#7 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(78): Application\Controller\PurchaseController->orderPlaceAction()
#8 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(106): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(138): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#12 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#14 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(332): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 /var/www/html/index.php(54): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#16 {main}
```

Comment: This's not error message, it's the class of exception. We need description to understand what's wrong. Can you post error message's description?

Comment: Also, you should not use your real username (and password), as well as real IP-addresses.

Comment: thank's a lot to guide

Comment: please help me to resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

Well if you check the [support page for error code 78754](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754) of google, they mentions few possible problems.

If you're sure about your mail and password, please be sure you don't request too frequently. They says you shouldn't make request more than 10 minutes.

Also if you're using 2-steps verification, you will need to create application based password or you'll have to use oAuth to access gmail.

I suggest you read this [this article](https://docs.maildev.com/article/121-gmail-web-login-required-error---answer78754-failure) too.